# error "euc-word-view.officeapps.live.com took too long to respond" when opening SharePoint online Word documents on browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, word

I have SharePoint Online site that contains Document Library with Word document, below are the errors messages when I try to open the word documents using the broswer

**Chrome Error**
euc-word-view.officeapps.live.com took too long to respond

**IE Error**
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address https://euc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

**on Fiddler I get this error**

[Fiddler] The connection to 'euc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com' failed. 
Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

What is blocking the connection, could it be firewall?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something we can solve as it is a service issue. You should open a case with Office 365 support, either through the Portal, or if you have a Premier contract, through support.microsoft.com.